# how to random questions in flash cs3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i have created a multiple choice type of game using flash cs5. the program i created is working but it does not show the things that im expecting for it to happen.

---

i am encountering few errors(which are not really errors in the codes). some of these so called errors are:

1. you see, I would like to have my questions taken from the xml file be random, i know that the code that must be used is `var random=Math.ceil(Math.random()*30);` wherein it should random 1 number only from the questions in the xml which is 30 in total. i dont know where or how should i insert the code.
2. in the game, the player must answer the question correctly,if the answer is correct,it should proceed to the scoreboard. else it should show the next question and count the wrong answer.5% will be deducted to the total grade for every wrong answer. but the problem is, **whether it shows the correct or wrong answer,it still doesn't go to the scoreboard**
3. i haven't inserted a timer yet that is essential/ needed to the game. im still trying to find out how to do so since the timer will indicated the deduction in the score. here is the thought: *for example in each game encounter (or battle) a certain amount of time will be given to the player(let us say 20secs) the player must answer the questions correctly within the time limit.if the player answered it correctly,it should proceed to the next frame(shows score)else 5% of the total score will be deducted*

i guess i could handle the timer, but i would really need your help on the first 2,my partner are still very new at flash. we have spent a lot of time already debugging the code but was unable to find a solution to the problem. thanks in advance for those who would help.

here is some of the codes in the program (actually the main code)

function QuizItem(question)
{
    this.question=question;
    this.answers=new Array();
    this.numOfAnswers=0;
    this.correctAnswer=0;
    this.getQuestion=function()
    {
        return this.question;
    }
    this.addAnswer=function(answer, isCorrectAnswer)
    {
        this.answers[this.numOfAnswers]=answer;
        if (isCorrectAnswer)
            this.correctAnswer=this.numOfAnswers;
        this.numOfAnswers++;
    }

```
this.getAnswer=function(answerNumberToGet)
{
    return this.answers[answerNumberToGet];
}

this.getCorrectAnswerNumber=function()
{
    return this.correctAnswer;
}

this.checkAnswerNumber=function(userAnswerNumber)
{
    if (userAnswerNumber==this.getCorrectAnswerNumber())
        gotoAndPlay("Correct");
    else
        gotoAndPlay("Wrong");
}
this.getNumOfAnswers=function()
{
    return this.answers.length; 
}
 }

 function onQuizData(success)
 {
var quizNode=this.firstChild;
var quizTitleNode=quizNode.firstChild;  
title=quizTitleNode.firstChild.nodeValue;

var i=0;
// <items> follows <title>
var itemsNode=quizNode.childNodes[1];
while (itemsNode.childNodes[i])
{
    var itemNode=itemsNode.childNodes[i];
    // <item> consists of  <question> and one or more <answer>
    // <question> always comes before <answer>s (node 0 of <item>)
    var questionNode=itemNode.childNodes[0];
    quizItems[i]=new QuizItem(questionNode.firstChild.nodeValue);
    var a=1;        
    // <answer> follows <question>
    var answerNode=itemNode.childNodes[a++];
    while (answerNode)
    {
        var isCorrectAnswer=false;
        if (answerNode.attributes.correct=="y")
            isCorrectAnswer=true;
        quizItems[i].addAnswer(answerNode.firstChild.nodeValue, isCorrectAnswer);
        // goto the next <answer>
        answerNode=itemNode.childNodes[a++];
    }
    i++;
}
gotoAndPlay("Start");
 }

 var quizItems=new Array();
 var myData=new XML();
 myData.ignoreWhite=true;
 myData.onLoad=onQuizData;
 myData.load("quiz1.xml");
 stop();
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but your code looks like actionscript 2

Answer (score 0):

You've got a LOT of issues going on here. I'm only going to address how you should be loading the quiz XML and a general procedure for displaying a random item from the list of questions:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var quizItems:Array;
var quizData:XML;

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataComplete);
xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onDataError);
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("INSERT XML URL HERE"));

function onDataComplete(evt:Event):void
{
    quizData = new XML(xmlLoader.data);
    var quizList:XMLList = quizData..item;

    createItems();

    showQuestion();
}

function createItems():void
{
    quizItems = new Array();

    // Grab each <item> node from the xml and stick it in an array.
    for each(var item:XML in quizList) quizItems.push(item);    
}

function showQuestion():void
{
    // TODO: Remove any previous question/answer items.

    // Double-check that the quizItems array is not at length 0, which means it should be repopulated.
    if (quizItems.length == 0) createItems();

    // Pick a random index based on the length of the quizItems array (which will shrink over time).
    var index:uint = Math.floor(Math.random() * quizItems.length);

    // Remove the item from the array and store it in a variable (so the item cannot be randomly chosen twice).
    var quizItemData:XML = quizItems.splice(index, 1)[0];

    // Grab the <question> node. 
    var questionNode:XML = quizItemData.question[0];
    // TODO: Take some action with the <question> data, such as assigning it to a text field.
    // Ex - myQuestionField.text = questionNode.toString();

    // Grab all the <answer> nodes as an XML list.
    var answerList:XMLList = quizItemData.answer;
    for each (var answerNode:XML in answerList) {
        // TODO: Take some action with each of the <answer> nodes.
        // Ex - myAnswerButton.labelText = answerNode.toString();
        // Ex - myAnswerButton.isCorrectAnswer = (answerNode.@correct == "y");
        // TODO: Position each answer item.
    }

    // TODO: Any remaining display tasks such as intro animation, etc.
}

function onDataError(evt:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("ERROR: " + evt.text);
}
```